# Refer to a class instance from a NSString

Tags: objective-c, object, nsstring, instance-variables

I have the following NSUrl objects :

```
NSURL * urlImage1 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url1];
NSURL * urlImage2 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url2];
NSURL * urlImage3 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url3];    
NSURL * urlImage4 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url4];    
NSURL * urlImage5 = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:url5];
```

and the following method that expect a NSUrl pointer as a parameter :

```
-(void)loadImageInBackground:(NSURL *)urlImage
```

Now.If I have a string like @"urlImage1" how can I pass it as a parameter to loadImageInBackground: ?
There's anyway apart from pushing everything inside a NSArray?I'm curious.

Thanks
Luca

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: I want to pass the string @"urlImage1" to my method..and refer to the NSurl named urlImage1

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the NSURL objects in a dictionary, and use the strings as keys.

Comment: What are you looking for? A dictionary is the best way of associating an object with a string.

Answer (score 0):

Except for debugging symbols (which are usually stripped from the executable, anyway), Objective-C (like many compiled languages) doesn't keep the names of local variables in the compiled program. There's simply no way to refer to a variable by its name, because the variable no longer has a name. It's just an address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your urls were object properties you could make them KVC Compliant

Making a Class KVC Compliant

The NSKeyValueCoding informal protocol makes KVC possible. Two of its methods — `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:` — are particularly important because they fetch and set a property’s value when given its key. NSObject provides a default implementation of these methods, and if a class is compliant with key-value coding, it can rely on this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's wrong with pushing all elements in an array? The pattern url1, url2, url3... pretty much calls for a collection type data structure. You could of course also use another collection type like NSSet.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"url1", @"url2", @"url3", @"url4", @"url5", nil];
set enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) [{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:obj];
    [yourLoader loadImageInBackground:url];
}];
```

If you're looking for something like this (pseudocode):

```
this.myIVar = ""
s="myIVar"
this[s]="lolz"
trace(this.myIVar)  //Expected: lolz
```

I don't think this is something Objective-C supports nor do I think it would be easier to read compared to the above.